# Alphabet Adjacent Pairs in Sequence code

Tags: java

Alphabet Adjacent Pairs in Sequence

Accept a string S which contains only lower case alphabets and print the count of instances C where in a pair of adjacent characters, the right character is next to the left character in the original alphabetical sequence.

Boundary Condition(s):
1 <= Length of S <= 1000

Input Format:
The first line contains S.

Output Format:
The first line contains the integer value C

Example Input/Output 1:
Input:
abegh

Output:
2

Explanation:
ab gh are the two instances.

Example Input/Output 2:
Input:
abcdef

Output:
5

Explanation:
ab bc cd de ef are the five instances.

My Solution:

```
import java.util.*;
public class adj{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    String s=sc.next();
    char t,t1;
    String r[]=new String[100];
    char a[]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r','s', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y' ,'z'};
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<(s.length()-1);i++)
    {
        t=s.charAt(i);
        t1=s.charAt(i+1);
        //r[i]=t+t1;
        if(t==(a[i]))
        { 
            if(t1==(a[i+1]))
                {
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(count);
  }
}
```

but this code prints only 1 for testcase abegh instead of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking for the letters that are on the same spot in the alphabet.

abcdefghij  <- 'a' has index [0], 'g' has index [6]

abegh <- 'a' has index [0], 'g' has index [3]

So you check for 'a', but don't check for 'g'

In your code you would want to replace

```
if(t==(a[i]))
    {
        if(t1==(a[i+1]))
            {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        continue;
    }
```

with

```
for(int j=0;j<(a.length()-1);j++)
    {
        if (t == a[j]){
            if(t1==(a[j+1]))
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            continue;
        }
    }
```

There are simpler solutions for this particular problem, like, you could use hashmap, for example, which would make you code faster. But since it's a school assignment, I guess it's not that important.

The bottomline is: for your approach you need inner loop to go over the alphabet letters.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
char s[1002];
scanf("%s",s);
int ac=0;
int an = strlen(s);
for(int i=0;i<an-1;i++)
{
  if((s[i+1]-s[i])==1){
    ac+=1;
  }
}
printf("%d",ac);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're developing an algorithm, you can use TDD. Go step by step and implement the functionality as you go, making sure all tests pass after you make a new production code addition. For your assignment, I came up with the following code (the input length condition is not fulfilled as I apparently missed that one, but you can implement that yourself):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class CharsTest {

    private class Chars {

        private void validateInput(String input) {
            if (!input.matches("^[a-z]*$")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input only accepts lowercase alphabetic characters.");
            }
        }

        public int count(String input) {
            validateInput(input);

            int counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; ++i) {
                if (input.charAt(i) + 1 == input.charAt(i + 1)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            return counter;
        }
    }

    private Chars chars = new Chars();

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnZeroOnEmptyString() {
        String input = "";
        int actual = chars.count(input);
        assertEquals(0, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnZeroOnNonEmptyStringWithZeroSequences() {
        String input = "zyxcba";
        int actual = chars.count(input);
        assertEquals(0, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRejectUppercaseAlpha() {
        try {
            chars.count("ABC");
            fail("Expected an exception.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // ok
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRejectNonAlpha() {
        try {
            chars.count("123 $%^");
            fail("Expected an exception.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // ok
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnOneWhenOneSequenceIsFound() {
        String input = "acdgix";
        int actual = chars.count(input);
        assertEquals(1, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCorrectlyCountAllSequences() {
        String input = "abcehpqtyz"; // ab, bc, pq, yz
        int actual = chars.count(input);
        assertEquals(4, actual);
    }
}
```

Note that I took a completely different approach to checking whether two characters form a valid pair: I take two adjacent chars in the string, say `A` and `B`, and check whether `A` is exactly one less than `B`. Since `char` is in fact a numeric value, you can easily confirm that the values of alphabetic characters form a numeric sequence.